# Odoo 10: Is possible to handle an action window through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, window, action, handle, odoo-10

I wonder if once I created an action window it can be handled by a Javascript module, such as buttons, fields (or create them in there).

By another hand, I want to ask if is possible to call an action window from a custom button in a form view through Javascript as well?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. I had done this with an input textarea field. In my case I created custom search field in systray. From that textarea field when you hit enter after entering value in it then this will open a form view. You can do with your button also.

Comment: That's great. I asked for this because I have created an action window with one field and a custom button as well, but I need that button can do something else like, after a method is executed from that button, it adds another HTML element to the view as an <img> for example and this can be done by a javascript module, I guess. 

From what object do I have to extend to make it works in that action window form view?. Is this possible?

I'm a new working on Odoo, to be honest.

Comment: So you need to insert button or an input field. And after clicking on that button or entering a value in a field and hitting enter key you need to add and runtime html element in a form view. Is this you want to do ? Or else ??

Comment: Something like that. That is the case..
The method loads an URL and downloads an image from that URL, in this case, a captcha image, and it will be saved in a directory. When the method finished the image has to be just by the field side where the captcha code will be written. But I can achieve that, I don't now what object I have to instantiate in javascript to work with an action window.

Comment: You need to instantiate object of action_manager.js situated in web/static/src/js. From that object you can give action to your form.

Comment: I'm sorry the delay to answer. Ok, I don't understand a lot how to use it. can you show some example?, since, when I researched about this, I just found how to execute the action window from action_manager, but not how to handle the form inside this action.

Comment: You can take reference from board/static/src/js/dashboard.js This might be helpful to you.